# pylab scatter plot appears transposed

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I have been playing with various interpolation techniques - and particularly like the varieties shown in the youtube video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cJLVhdj0j4

However, the scatter module plots the points in the wrong location. I have transposed them below (Example 5) to make it work, but this does not work if the area of interest is not centred on the origin (Test_Rbf).

Am I mis-understanding something fundamental, or is this a problem in the pylab scatter module?

```
# Example 5 
#
# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cJLVhdj0j4

import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import pylab as py

def func(x,y):
return (x+y)*np.cos(-5.0*x + 4.0*y)

x = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0,size=50)
y = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0,size=50)
fvals = func(x,y)

newfunc = interpolate.Rbf(x, y, fvals, function='multiquadric')
xnew, ynew = np.mgrid[-1:1:100j, -1:1:100j]

fnew = newfunc(xnew, ynew)
true = func(xnew, ynew)

py.figure()
py.clf()
py.imshow( fnew, extent=[-1,1,-1,1], cmap=py.cm.jet)
# py.scatter( x, y, 30, fvals, cmap=py.cm.jet)
py.scatter( y, -x, 30, fvals, cmap=py.cm.jet)

py.show()

from enthought.mayavi import mlab

mlab.clf()
mlab.surf(xnew, ynew, fnew*2)
```

Comment: There is (unfortunately) a x<->y flip between image/matrix coordinates and geometric coordinates.  Typically when plotting functions we think of points as `(x, f(x))` but when looking at images/matrices we think `(row, column)`.  When you plot an image with `imshow` it maps row -> y and col -> x.  To make things worse, in images/matrices row increases _down_ and in Cartesian cords y increases _up_.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
ynew, xnew = np.mgrid[-1:1:100j, -2:2:100j]
```

instead of

```
xnew, ynew = np.mgrid[-1:1:100j, -2:2:100j]
```

then `xnew` will vary as you move across columns, and `ynew` will vary as you move down the rows. (I changed the x-range from [-1,1] to [-2,2] to make it clear what numbers control which range.)

Combine that with @hitzg's suggestion to add `origin='lower'` to the call to `imshow`, and you get:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2015)
def func(x,y):
    return (x+y)*np.cos(-5.0*x + 4.0*y)

x = np.random.uniform(-2.0, 2.0, size=50)
y = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=50)
fvals = func(x,y)

newfunc = interpolate.Rbf(x, y, fvals, function='multiquadric')
ynew, xnew = np.mgrid[-1:1:100j, -2:2:100j]

fnew = newfunc(xnew, ynew)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(fnew, extent=[-2,2,-1,1], cmap=plt.cm.jet, origin='lower')
plt.scatter(x, y, s=30, c=fvals, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic ;-)      HappyLeapSecond